# Как разбить строку на PHP?

Tags: php

Как при помощи PHP выбрать из строки нужное?
Например есть строка:

```
[id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]
```

Мне нужно разбить ее на массив:

```
id = ИД
mess = Текст
date = Дата
```

Проблема заключается в том, как сделать правильно с блоком "`[mess]Текст[/mess]`". Необходимо выбрать весь текст, который находится между `[mess]` и `[/mess]`.

Comment: Имена «тегов» фиксированы и известны заранее, или надо уметь разобрать любой тег, напр. `[stackoverflow]Ничоси[/stackoverflow]`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

*Предполагаю*, что теги формируются программно, а контент их может быть безобразно любым, но не содержащим, даже случайно, валидные теги в полном виде.

---

Можно функцией php [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strpos.php) по очереди находить каждый из элементов в квадратных скобках, и затем взять нужные части строки ф-ей [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php).

Напр. для `[id]ИД[/id]` сначала найти позицию "[id]" (ф-я вернёт 0), узнать длину этого тега (4, значит, строка «ИД» начинается с 0+4=4), затем найти начало "[/id]" (вернёт 6). Т.е. нужные символы – с 4 по 6 позицию: `mb_substr($line, 4, 6-4)`

Раз это понадобится для каждого «тега», обернём в ф-ю:

```
function getTagContent( $line, $tagName) {
    $encoding   = mb_detect_encoding($line);
    $tagOpen    = '['  . $tagName . ']';
    $tagClose   = '[/' . $tagName . ']'; 

    $open   = mb_strpos($line, $tagOpen, 0, $encoding);
    $start  = $open + mb_strlen($tagOpen, $encoding);
    $close  = mb_strpos($line, $tagClose, 0, $encoding);

    return mb_substr($line, $start, $close - $start, $encoding);
}
```

И останется собрать результат:

```
$line = '[id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]';

$result = array(
    'id'    => getTagContent( $line, 'id'),
    'mess'  => getTagContent( $line, 'mess'),
    'date'  => getTagContent( $line, 'date'),
);
```

Comment: сделать сложно -> очень просто , сделать просто -> очень сложно ))

Comment: @redroid с регуляркой ответ очевиден, захотелось напильником поработать )

Comment: угу , знакомо )

Comment: $line = '[date][id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]'; – чувствуешь подставу?

Comment: или так – $line = '[id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст [data]Дата[/date]';

Comment: @korytoff Моя гипотеза, что теги формируются программно, а контент их может быть безобразно любым, но не содержащим, даже случайно, валидные теги в полном виде.

Comment: @Sergiks да, но если строка будет большой с большим кол-вом тегов, то ваш скрипт будет много лишней работы делать. Вот если бы вырезать из строки часть уже найденной инфы, то последующие операции были бы еще быстрее

Comment: @korytoff достаточно ввести индекс позиции в строке, где остановились, и дальше искать, начиная с него. А ещё быстрее на C написать. Но не будем.

Comment: @Sergiks ))))))

Comment: @Sergiks а индекс где остановились не подойдет, теги же не обязательно в том же порядке будут идти, нужно именно обрезать

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать регулярные выражения два примера для preg_match*

1. по конкретным тегам - https://regex101.com/r/yH1wT8/1
2. универсальный - `\[([a-zA-Z]+)=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[\/\1\]`

Как вариант, есть класс через PECL ставится - php.net/manual/ru/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет функционал регулярных выражений. Воспользуйтесь PHP-функцией [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php).
Подобрать само регулярное выражение удобно с помощью [этого сервиса](http://www.regexr.com/).

[Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) вы сможете найти справку по элементам регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("#\[id\](?<id>.*?)\[\/id\] \[mess\](?<mess>.*?)\[\/mess\] \[date\](?<date>.*?)\[\/date\]#" , $str , $res);

print_r($res);
```

Comment: `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat ..`

Comment: `$str = "[id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]";
preg_match("#\[id\](.*?)\[\/id\] \[mess\](.*?)\[\/mess\] \[date\](.*?)\[\/date\]#" , $str , $res);

print_r($res);` ага * c ? перепутал местами , получите вот такое http://prntscr.com/90hnsq

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Comment: ТС требуется массив иного вида.

Comment: Тогда вот так , изменил основной ответ - получите http://prntscr.com/90j2dp

Comment: А если порядок измениться? Теги добавятся? Удаляться? Пробелы уберут?

Comment: есть простая задача , есть простое решение . Если бы у задачи были условия , решение было бы другое .

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобных проблем с вырезанием текста написал набор функций. Сначала на C++, а потом и на php перенес.

```
// Part Line
function PartLine($line, &$two, $el){
    if(($p=strpos($line, $el))===false){
        $two="";
        return $line;
    }

    $two=substr($line, $p+strlen($el));
    return substr($line, 0, $p);
}

function PartLineDouble($line, $el, $er){
    $ret=PartLine($line, $line, $el);
    $ret=PartLine($line, $line, $er);
    return $ret;
}
```

Решение вашей задачи:

```
$id = PartLineDouble($line, '[id]', '[/id]');
$mess= PartLineDouble($line, '[mess]', '[/mess]');
$date= PartLineDouble($line, '[date]', '[/date]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь на здоровье ([phpFidle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff54de283f6c2c6ca34427792204ca4b5b3d029b)):

```
<?php
/**
 * Parse string – "[id]ИД[/id]";
 * @var string $str
 * @return array
 * @throws \Exception
**/
function parseStringWithTag($str) {
    $startFirstTag = $endFirstTag = $startSecondTag = $endSecondTag = -1;
    $startTag = $endTag = $val = '';
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if($startFirstTag >= 0 && $str[$i] !== ']') {
            $startTag .= $str[$i];
        }
        if($startSecondTag >= 0 && $str[$i] !== ']' && $str[$i] !== '/') {
            $endTag .= $str[$i];
        }
        if($str[$i] === '[') {
            if((!isset($str[$i+1])) || $str[$i+1] === '/') {
                $startSecondTag = $i;
            } else {
                $startFirstTag = $i;
            }
        }
        if($endFirstTag >= 0 && $startSecondTag === -1) {
            $val .= $str[$i];
        }
        if($str[$i] === ']') {
            if($endFirstTag >= 0) {
                if($startTag === $endTag) {
                    $result[$startTag] = $val;
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception('Parsing string "' . $str . '" error');
                }
                // all reset;
                $endFirstTag = $endSecondTag = -1;
                $startTag = $endTag = $val = '';
            } else {
                $endFirstTag = $i;
            }
            $startFirstTag = $startSecondTag = -1;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$str = "[id]ИД[/id] [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]"; // проверка корректной строки
$str2 = "[id]ИД [mess]Текст[/mess] [date]Дата[/date]"; // проверка не корректной строки
try{
    $result = parseStringWithTag($str);
    var_dump($result);
    $result = parseStringWithTag($str2);
    var_dump($result);
}catch(\Exception $e) {
    // ошибка парсинга
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

### UPD

Время работы данного алгоритма линейно + теги могут быть любые в строке + немного адаптировать под повторяющиеся теги

Comment: Почему `strlen()` – по каждому байту двухбайтовых символов цикл проверки крутить? `echo strlen('[ИД]'); // 6` Есть же [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php) и другие `mb_*`

Comment: И текст со скобкой не пройдёт: `[mess]Привет, ][ ![/mess]`

Comment: @Sergiks а в чем проблема пройтись по всем символам? Нету проблем с `strlen()`, а скобки в тексте использовать конечно нельзя, попробуй в `json` добавить в строку {} или []

Comment: «Проблема» в том, что в кодировке UTF-8 вы на символе, напр., «И» выполните цикл дважды, т.к. он состоит из 2 байт – добавьте вывод `$str[$i]` в начале каждой итерации. // Тут не json, а что-то совсем простое, скорее всего, не продуманное глубже названий полей в квадратных скобках. ТС это никак не описал, поэтому сие моё предположение может быть ошибочным )

Comment: @Sergiks я прекрасно понимаю, что здесь многобайтовые символы, в цикле идет обращение через индекс символа и легкие операции сравнения, так что скорость большая. А вот как пройти по всем многобайтовым символам в цикле и обращаться к ним по индексу?

Comment: @Sergiks и так же самая логика по скорости может относится к сравнению `strpos` и `mb_strpos`, как думаете какая функция работает быстрее?

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, почему в XML используются квадратные скобки, но это легко исправить

```
$str = strtr(htmlspecialchars($s),'[]','<>');
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><doc>'.$str.'</doc>';
$arr = (array)simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $arr['mess'];
```